# Вставка многострочной string в txt файл

Tags: javascript, строки, файлы, jade

Имеется такая многострочная строка.

```
let text = `Мат в 3 хода
Белые: Крb8, Лe8, Сg8,  e6,  f6, Кg4
Черные: Крh8,  e5,  b4,  c4,  d4,  e4, Сd3, Фb2, Кc2, Сc1
1.e6-e7 ! угроза:
        2.Сg8-e6 + 
            2...Крh8-h7 
                3.Сe6-f5 # 
    1...Сc1-h6 
        2.Кg4*h6 угроза:
                3.Кh6-f7 # 
    1...Кc2-e3 
        2.Кg4-h6 угроза:
                3.Кh6-f7 # 
    1...e4-e3 
        2.Кg4*e5 угроза:
                3.Кe5-f7 # 
            2...Сd3-g6 
                3.Кe5*g6 #`;
```

Пытаюсь записать в файл.

```
document.write('<a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '" download="text.txt">text.txt</a>')
```

Но все записывается в одну строку. Как записать в файл "как есть"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но все записывается в одну строку. Как записать в файл "как есть"?

Вот так например:

```js
let text = `Мат в 3 хода
Белые: Крb8, Лe8, Сg8,  e6,  f6, Кg4
Черные: Крh8,  e5,  b4,  c4,  d4,  e4, Сd3, Фb2, Кc2, Сc1
1.e6-e7 ! угроза:
        2.Сg8-e6 + 
            2...Крh8-h7 
                3.Сe6-f5 # 
    1...Сc1-h6 
        2.Кg4*h6 угроза:
                3.Кh6-f7 # 
    1...Кc2-e3 
        2.Кg4-h6 угроза:
                3.Кh6-f7 # 
    1...e4-e3 
        2.Кg4*e5 угроза:
                3.Кe5-f7 # 
            2...Сd3-g6 
                3.Кe5*g6 #`;

text = text.replace(/\n/gu, "\r\n") // Добавьте это \r\n
console.log(text);

document.write('<a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '" download="text.txt">text.txt</a>')
```

Comment: Не помогает. Всё также в одну строку записывается в файл. А в консоли и без replace выводился как надо.

Comment: @АлександрКасиков исправил.